# How to manipulate a individual edge

Tags: mesh

How can I lower the edge indicated with red arrow to the edge indicated with the green arrow.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to merge the 2 edges, you should first enable the *Auto-Merge* option:

[image]

Then select both the 2 edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* to bridge. Now select the top edge and slide it down with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. You may not even need the bridge if the 2 edges are correctly aligned, in that case enable the *Snap* (*Vertex* mode) and the *Auto-Merge* options and move down the top edge.

[image]

Comment: I work with Blender 2.79

When I do that, the whole mesh moves and not just the edge.

Comment: maybe you've enabled the Proportional Editing option? (small sphere icon, blue when activated)

Comment: That's it, thank you very much!